# What is the maximum CFBundleVersion

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect, info-plist

our build system automatically sets the CFBundleVersion to the number of commits in git. When we set this up we thought this would be a good way to track what was built and not have to update the build number manually.

The question is what happens when we reach really high numbers? We're currently at around 2500.

Thanks
Maciej

Answer (score 1):

It's held as a string, and you're highly unlikely to hit any limits based on the number of commits to a git repository.

Answer (score 0):

Maximum number is 1,000 over.
Because, My project has 1052.1052 for CFBundleversion. And I can upload/submit it project to the iTunese connect.